# asp.net core 2.2 redirect identity loginpath

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

in our current setup we have a known path for logging in.
But now that we are using core 2.2 I cannot fix the current problem; That is always using loginPath: `/Identity/Account/Login` but we would like to change this.

Reading a lot on StackOverflow and others, I cannot seem to fix it.
So now i have a complete new MVC app trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

In my startup I have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        //                .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login2");
    });

   services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong? Better yet; what is the solution :)

Comment: so basicly i want to move away from the default `identity/account/login` to `account/login2` or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so as it turns out;

I needed to scaffold an identity item (like `login`) and in the login razor page (login.cshtml) you can add:

```
@page "~/account/login2"
```

this is probably also you can fix with the routing in razor during startup:

```
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {...});
```

haven't tried it out yet, but that is something else..

cheers